# Should I use IFormFile to Upload Files in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iformfile

I can understand using `IFormFile` to upload files in an MVC web app but what is the correct method of uploading files using ASP.NET Core when writing an API supporting Swagger?

## With IFormFile

```
[HttpPost("{id}/content", Name ="PostZipFile")]
[Consumes("application/zip")]
public Task<IActionResult> PostZipFile(int id, [FromBody] IFormFile zipFile)
{
}
```

## Using Body.Stream

```
[HttpPost("{id}/content", Name ="PostZipFile")]
[Consumes("application/zip")]
public Task<IActionResult> PostZipFile(int id)
{
    this.Response.Body.Stream
}
```

Comment: It still applies to WebApi-esque controllers. In ASP.NET Core both are unified in a single API. You just need to send the ajax post request with `multipart/form-data` encoding type

Comment: Hey, which do you think is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
[HttpPost("{id}/content", Name ="PostZipFile")]
public Task<IActionResult> PostZipFile(int id,IFormFile zipFile)
{
}
```

And make sure that on the Client Side, the Form Action or Ajax request has: `encoding type= "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: i was missing enctype: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">